# iOS - Objective C dynamic framework emit bitcode for arch x86_64 (simulator)

Tags: ios, xcode9, bitcode, dynamic-frameworks

Have setup a sample on Github, I'm using Xcode v 9.4.1
https://github.com/iousin/TreeFramework

Basically I'm trying to build my framework to include bitcode in the x86_64 simulator build. I tried various settings and tried building on command line, xcodebuild refuses to include bitcode in my simulator build, however it is very happy to include it in the arm64 (device) build.

All the following commands should be able to run from the same folder the above framework is checked out.

Following are the commands I've tried to build the above framework:

```
    xcodebuild ENABLE_BITCODE[sdk=iphone*]=YES BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode DYLIB_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION=1 -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release -target TreeFramework clean build

    xcodebuild OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" ENABLE_BITCODE[sdk=iphone*]=YES BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release -target TreeFramework clean build

    xcodebuild OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" ENABLE_BITCODE="YES" BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE="bitcode" -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release -target TreeFramework clean build
```

Ran the following to verify bitcode is emitted (it doesn't in this case).

```
    otool -arch x86_64 -l build/Release-iphonesimulator/TreeFramework.framework/TreeFramework | grep LLVM
```

However when I build for a device, bitcode is included.

```
    xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release -target TreeFramework clean build
```

Verify bitcode is emitted:

```
    otool -arch arm64 -l build/Release-iphoneos/TreeFramework.framework/TreeFramework | grep LLVM
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Any solution on this ?

Comment: Hi, So far don't think it's possible, one of the apple engineer confirmed this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/111523